# Covering a ball by rotations

Tags: geometry

I'm reading a paper that claims the following and I would appreciate a proof or reference.
Say we have a ball $B_r(x)$ with radius $r$ and center $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$.
Pick a point $y \in \partial B_r(x)$ on the boundary and concider the ball $\overline{B_r(y)}$. Then it is always possible to apply $d(n)$ rotations $R_k$ such that

$$ B_r (x) \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{d(n)} R_k\left( B_r(x) \cap \overline{B_r(y)}\right).$$

In dimension $1$ and $2$ its clear that 1 repsectively 4 rotations are enough.
Is there a bound on the number of rotations needed $d(n)$?

Comment: In 3D, do you mean covering the (solid) ball ($x^2+y^2+z^2 \le r^2$) by (solid) balls (with the same radius) or covering the (surfacic...) sphere ($x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$) in 3D with (surfacic) disks ?

Comment: Solid ball in any dimension by rotations of the intersection with a ball of radius r and center on the boundary.  E.g. in 1 dimension with unit ball and y=1; the intersection would be [0,1] and a rotation by pi convers the original ball completely

Comment: Thnks for your reply. In dimension 3 : 4 spheres centered on the vertices of an inscribed regular tetrahedron look to be sufficient ; aren't they ?

Comment: Sorry. Yes maybe

Comment: I would like to know if there's a bound in d of the number of sufficient intersection